# ProcessBuilder failing with call to java -jar on packaged jar

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

My java uses ProcessBuilder to run several commands using other jar that I have added in the resources.

It works fine in Eclipse, but once I export it to executable jar, it doesn't work:

```
//Defs Class has this line
public final static String APKTOOLS_JAR_PATH = Defs.class.getResource("/apktool.jar").getPath();

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", Defs.APKTOOLS_JAR_PATH, "d", apkPath, "-o", decodePath, "-f");
pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = pb.start();
```

I get back:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile apktool.jar
```

Comment: apktool.jar may in fact not be right where it needs to be. Try to put it next to the main one?

Comment: just guessing here - but theres a leading "/" in the getResource line - maybe remove it? (using absolute pathnames vs relative) ..

Comment: The getPath() method of URL **does not** convert a URL to a valid file name.  Use `Paths.get(Defs.class.getResource("/apktool.jar").toURI()).toString()` instead.  Note that when running from a .jar, this will fail, because a resource in a .jar is not a separate file at all.  In that case, you will need to copy it out of the .jar;  I recommend copying it to a [temporary file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-).

Answer (score 0):

if your apktool.jar in the same directory as the your java class is running

```
public final static String APKTOOLS_JAR_PATH = Defs.class.getResource("apktool.jar").getPath();
```

where it takes the jar from relative path

but if you want that to be loaded from a absolute path leading slash / should  do that

```
public final static String APKTOOLS_JAR_PATH = Defs.class.getResource("/home/user/myjars/apktool.jar").getPath();
```

where leading slash considered as an absolute path